# Does this form of memory management make sense at all in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

In the life-cycle of my application, I have to re-create an ArrayList that contains other ArrayLists of objects (reading them from storage). The ArrayList is always assigned to the same data member in a class, essentially leaving the older ArrayList-of-ArrayLists dangling (unreference-able or inaccessible).

My understanding is that, unlike in C++, this doesn't result in a memory leak because the system knows when an object becomes unreference-able and frees the memory when/as it sees fit.

Still, old habits are hard to overcome and I am almost instinctively drawn to "help" the system by doing some cleanup myself before re-creating that ArrayList-of-ArrayLists:

```
for (InnerArray aList : outerArray)
  aList.clear();
outerArray.clear();
```

My questions:

1. Is this redundant?
2. Am I doing more harm than good?
3. Is this good in any way?
4. Why?

Comment: confirmed! clear() just makes the Objects in the List eligible for garbage collection. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is redundant. You are not helping those objects get freed, because garbage collection will already determine them to be unreachable. You can't make them more unreachable than they already are. So, you waste a little bit of processing time on something that accomplishes nothing.

The main problem, though, is that you are confusing other developers who will be wondering why you're clearing that array. They may waste their time trying to figure out why you were doing that, if there's some hidden reason that they didn't see at first.

A similar problem that C++ developers tend to have with Java code is making [finalizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer); in Java you almost never want to do this, as finalizers add an additional cost to garbage collection and they aren't a reliable way to free resources because they may not get called for a long time, or ever.

Comment: Thanks +1 for an enlightening answer. I will be awaiting more answers to get additional insights.

Comment: Here's a short article that explains the basics of how Java's type of GC works, it might help clarify some things for you: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html

Answer (score 4):

1. yup - Honestly I just don't get it. if you don't need an object anymore just make sure that you cannot access it anymore and you're good!
2. yup - invoking might use processing power, garbage collection would probably use less to get rid of an object. It might also be confusing as Nate suggested.
3. nope - I don't see anything good, sorry.
4. See above and welcome to Java! You can concentrate on the fun stuff now :)

P.S. I'm not sure about what I'm going to say now, but the `clear()` function might remove elements from an `ArrayList` just by making sure that you cannot access them anymore through the `ArrayList` variable. Probably it won't 'destroy' them but it will just make them eligible for garbage collection. It would be nice to know how that function is implemented...

P.P.S. You might be tempted to invoke GC yourself, don't do it! See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935218/destroying-objects-in-java/6935322#6935322).

**EDIT:**

Here is the `clear()` from `ArrayList`:

```
public void clear()
{
    if (size > 0)
    {
        modCount++;
        // Allow for garbage collection.
        Arrays.fill(data, 0, size, null);
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It would be nice to know how that function is implemented..."* - read the source Luke.

Comment: @Gevorg - "damn if I'm too lazy" back at you :-)

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is this redundant?

Yes.

> 2) Am I doing more harm than good?

Yes.

> 3) Is this good in any way?

No.

> 4) Why?

Calling `clear()` on an `ArrayList` changes the list's `size` field and then carefully assigns `null` to the elements of its backing array that that have just become invalid. The code of `clear()` needs to do this because the references in those elements could cause other objects to remain reachable; i.e. leak memory.

However, when an `ArrayList` becomes unreachable, the garbage collector won't *ever again* look at *any* of the elements of the backing array.  The GC's marking process only traverses the reachable objects, and the reclamation process doesn't look at the contents of garbage objects / arrays.

So, basically, calling `clear()` on an object that it about to become unreachable is a total waste of CPU cycles and memory / VM bandwidth.  (And of course it is redundant code that the next guy is going to scratch his head about ...)

---

In fact, it is even debatable whether calling `clear` and then reusing a list is a good idea at all:

- Calling `clear` doesn't release / resize the backing array, so you could be left with a huge backing array for a list whose size is usually small.
- It is not inconceivable that the garbage collector can free a large enough array and allocate a new one of the same size *faster* than `clear()` can do its job.  (For a start, the GC can use multiple processors, where a call to `clear()` will run on one thread.)

> Is there a scenario that actually justifies calling clear()?

The only scenario where its is absolutely necessary to clear/reuse a list is when something else references *that particular* list and you can't update the list references.

There may also be benefit in clearing / reusing lists on platform with constrained memory and/or a slow GC. However, I wouldn't attempt this "optimization" unless I had STRONG evidence that this was a problem.  (This kind of optimization makes your code more complicated, and can lead to performance problems of its own if it is done incorrectly.)

Comment: Thanks +1. According to your explanation, one needs to avoid calling clear() as much as possible. Is there a scenario that actually justifies calling clear()?

Comment: Your ArrayList holds your favorite CDs but someone else steals them! So you clear() your ArrayList and you have no CDs anymore (no memory management involved)... @Stephen: what do you mean with 'the reclamation process doesn't look at the contents of garbage objects/arrays'? If an ArrayList (an object) is not reachable it becomes eligible for gc. All its objects that are not reachable in any other ways will be marked as eligible as well. GC will have to get read at first level objects and all the ones that were accessible through them only.

Comment: @ateiob as Stephen said if you have a very memory constrained environment then using clear may be slightly advantageous.  Remember the GC does not necessarily run right after something goes out of scope, so if ArrayList bob already exists, then right after you call bob=new ArrayList(); you will have, until next time the GC runs, both the new bob and the old bob in memory....however keep in mind that that memory footprint, even for very large arrays, is really small.  Your ArrayList doesnt actually store the data, it is really just an array of pointers.