# Java - when is this object unloaded?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
    LinkedList <Mono> list = new LinkedList ();

    list.add(new Mono (2, 2));
    list.add(new Mono (1, -1));
    list.remove (1);
```

Now, when the second item in the list is removed, is the object destroyed? IE, it undergoes garbage collection?

Comment: This question is sort of vague. A *class* is not the same as an *instance* of said class (an "object"). Please consider making the question more clear (by being consistent) -- classes or objects?

Comment: Is your question "When is the second item from the array garbage collected?" The class itself is never unloaded, the object is garbage collected whenever the system decides to garbage collect. Calling System.gc() may make it happer sooner but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, that was my question, my poor understanding of OOP terminology kind of got in the way of asking it haha.

Comment: Do you need some special behavior when it's garbage-collected?

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT* for new question:

Yes, the object will be eligible for garbage collection when there are no strong references remaining.  However the JVM will try to do clean up garbage in big batches, so it could actually get collected at any arbitrary later time (or never if the JVM terminates before GC gets around to it)

*Old answer*:

Class unloading is a rare event, and will generally not happen in a timely manner (if at all.)

Specifically, even after it becomes eligible for collection it won't get collected along with "normal" new objects like your Mono instances - it's often in a special different pool (PermGen in the Oracle JVM)

You should assume that once a class is loaded it will stay loaded forever.  Once you get into web applications in containers this is not always true, but anyone that has worked in those environments can tell you generally how well it (doesn't) work.

Comment: It doesn't help that the code names the class explicitly, so I'd be surprised if it could be unloaded at all (unless the class is lazily loaded, but I had the impression that static initializers happened early).

Comment: So if I remove the item from the list that item will still hang around in memory? Nothings referencing it..shouldn't it undergo gc?

Comment: Ah, sorry, your question has changed since I wrote my answer.  I will update it.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage Collection in Java is generally non-deterministic insofar as *when* it will occur and which eligible objects the GC will evict ("free") when a GC cycle *does occur*.

The only *reliable* rule is thus:

1. An object will remain available (will not be GC'ed/freed/evicted) as long as it is *strongly-reachable*. (See "The Reachability Lifecycle of Objects" in [Chapter 9 of Inside the Java Virtual Machine](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/gcP.html) for what this means -- very good reading in general, if a tad dated.)

In the posted code the `remove` will result in the second object `new Mono(1, -1)` being *eligible* for reclamation as there are no longer any strong references to it (the object is no longer strongly-reachable). The actual eviction (if it occurs) will happen "sometime later" and may not even be the next GC cycle. Using finalizers (ick) further complicates the matter.

Note that an object is *never guaranteed* to be GC'ed (the JVM may just terminate [ab]normally, for instance) and the exact semantics of particular GC implementation can differ and still be a conforming virtual machine -- it all comes down to reachability.

Happy coding.

Comment: @Steven Schlansker Updated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when the Object is unloaded?

An empty list is still a list, so it'll stay in memory.  It is cleared when you go:

list=somethingElse;

That is assuming that you don't assign anything else to be list.

As far as the class definition itself, it should stay in memory forever.  Class definitions are in the permanent generation.

As a side note.  list cannot be garbage collected at that point.  Because you can add things to it after if you clear it.

Answer (score 0):

The class "Mono" cannot be unloaded since there are still references to it. The type of the list refers to it and there is still one element in the list.

I suppose you did not mean to ask whether the class is unloaded, but whether the instance is "unloaded". Each instance of a class, each object, is allocated on the heap. When the object is no longer in use, the space that it occupies in the heap can be reclaimed. This does not happen immediately however. All JVM implementations that I know use a garbage collector to clean up the memory. To really simplify things here: when there is no more space free to create a new object on the heap, the garbage collector kicks in and will check which parts of the heap are still in use. The parts that are no longer in use, can be reused for new objects.

So, the memory from an object that is no longer in use, will only be reclaimed when the garbage collector kicks in. And this is something that cannot be predicted.

Answer (score 0):

the second object will be elligible for gargabe collection after removing it from the list, since there will be no more references to it .. hence out of scope .

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, so here's my spin.  Think about "scope", a concept in computer languages that describes where and when you can access a named bit of memory.

Here's your original code, with your purported removal of the second list member added:

```
LinkedList <Mono> list = new LinkedList ();

list.add(new Mono (2, 2));
list.add(new Mono (1, -1));
list.remove (1);
list.remove (2);`
```

At the point of list.remove(2), the object "list" can still be referenced.  Sure, it's empty, but then you might decide to add a new Mono to it.  You can because "list" is still *in scope*, so "list" is not reclaimed.

Compare to this:

```
{
  LinkedList <Mono> list = new LinkedList ();

  list.add(new Mono (2, 2));
  list.add(new Mono (1, -1));
  list.remove (1);
  list.remove (2);`
}
```

After the closing brace, "list" can no longer be referenced.  "list" was declared inside that scope, and when the scope was exited, "list" was removed from the namespace along with the scope itself.  At *that* point, garbage collection *could* happen, since no one could possibly use "list" again.

Keep an eye on the scope of your objects.  If you want to influence garbage collection, keep the scope of your objects limited to the region where they are used.  As it happens, that is good programming style too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess people got confused with the terminology you used. I believed you are asking if your `Mono` object will be "deleted"/"garbage collected".

Let's take a look at the `remove(1)` that you are invoking...

This is the remove function that you are calling as defined in `java.util.LinkedList`:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    return remove(entry(index));
}
```

The function above calls the following (look at my comments in the code):

```
private E remove(Entry<E> e) {
if (e == header)
    throw new NoSuchElementException();

    E result = e.element;
    e.previous.next = e.next; //Preceding element refers now to the one after the element to be removed;
    e.next.previous = e.previous; //Next element refers now to the one before the one to be removed;
    e.next = e.previous = null; //Element to be removed doesn't refer to anything anymore;
    e.element = null;
    size--;
    modCount++;
    return result;
}
```

After the function you call terminates, there is no way to refer to your Mono(1, -1) anymore. That Mono Object is not accessible anymore. This means that it will become eligible for Garbage Collection. Keep in mind that "eligible" might mean that it never be garbage collected... More on GC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935218/destroying-objects-in-java/6935322#6935322).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that it should not matter to you when a Java object is garbage collected.  The only thing that you need to know is that it *will* get garbage collected *before your program runs out of memory* ... *provided* that the object is unreachable.

The complicate answer includes other things:

- The garbage collector *typically* runs at a time that you can't predict.
- You can call `System.gc()` to suggest that the JVM runs the GC run now, but:

  - the JVM may ignore this hint, and
  - it is generally a bad idea to do this.  (Running the GC is expensive, and your application has insufficient information to know when it is best to do this from an efficiency standpoint.)
- Any particular run of the GC is not guaranteed to reclaim all unreachable objects.  The GC has a lot of "smarts" that are aimed at making GC as efficient as possible, or reducing "pause" times.  One of the "smarts" is to not GC the entire heap every time.
- There are no guarantees that the GC will run at all, or that it will run before the JVM is shutdown.
- Because of the above, it is a **bad idea** to write an application so that it  *depends on* a specific object being reclaimed / deleted at a specific time.

---

(The one thing that *should* concern you in memory management is storage leaks; e.g. when your application keeps references to unwanted objects that prevent those objects from ever becoming unreachable.  But that's not what your question is about.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean is the instance of Mono eligible for garbage collection or is the instance of list eligible for garbage collection?

The instance of mono will be eligible for garbage collection when it is removed (assuming that the code has not created over references to it.

The list is NOT eligible for garbage collection just because it is emptied.  An empty list cannot be garbage collected because it is a valid object that can read and written to again.

An as others have pointed out.  We are talking about eligible for garbage collection.  The garbage collector does not necessarily run immediately.